# error- "Could not find file create\UI.xml" while create user in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I try to create another user in umbraco system. but when I click on button "create" (under users) I get this error:

> Could not find file
>   '\dev05-pc\c$\Users\moshel\source\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebAdmin\umbraco\config\create\UI.xml'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find
>   file
>   '\dev05-pc\c$\Users\moshel\source\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebAdmin\umbraco\config\create\UI.xml'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   '\dev05-pc\c$\Users\moshel\source\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebAdmin\umbraco\config\create\UI.xml'.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +382    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
>   checkHost) +736    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) +63
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
>   credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) +77
>   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type
>   ofObjectToReturn) +69
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +54
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +70
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack,
>   ContextCallback callback, Object state) +92
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +132
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +208
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) +132    System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader) +107    Umbraco.Web.UI.LegacyDialogHandler.GetXmlDoc() +136
>   Umbraco.Web.UI.LegacyDialogHandler.GetTaskForOperation(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, User umbracoUser, Operation op, String nodeType) +149
>   Umbraco.Web.UI.LegacyDialogHandler.UserHasCreateAccess(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, User umbracoUser, String nodeType) +13
>   Umbraco.Web.UI.Umbraco.CreateDialog.SecurityCheck(String
>   nodeTypeAlias) +71
>   Umbraco.Web.UI.Umbraco.CreateDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +50
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +780
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2110.0

any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check, please, that  '\dev05-pc\c$\Users\moshel\source\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebAdmin\umbraco\config\create\UI.xml'. file exists and check please "Umbraco" folder permissions

Permissions should be like described here - https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/permissions